# Adafruit_GFX setRotation not working when called from within a class

Tags: lcd, library, adafruit

Using an ILI9341. I'm trying to set the rotation from within a class, but it's not working.  The code is very straight forward.

If I rotate in the class, the setRotation code does not work but the text is still printed. The pointer is set properly and the text is still printed, it just doesn't get rotated.

Outside of the class, the rotation works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "Adafruit_ILI9341.h"

#define TFT_DC 5
#define TFT_CS 3

Adafruit_ILI9341 *tft;
uint8_t newRotationAngle = 0;

void drawStuff() {
    tft->setTextColor(map(rand(), 0, RAND_MAX, 0, 0xffff));
    tft->fillRect(0, 0, tft->width(), tft->height(), ILI9341_BLACK);
    tft->setCursor(0, 0);

    tft->print(F("01234567890"));
    delay(250);
}


class test {
public:
    void init(Adafruit_GFX *_p) { ptrTft = _p; };

    void inClassRotation(int newRotation) {
        ptrTft->setRotation(newRotation);
        drawStuffInClass();
    };

    void drawStuffInClass() {
        ptrTft->setTextColor(map(rand(), 0, RAND_MAX, 0, 0xffff));
        ptrTft->fillRect(0, 0, ptrTft->width(), ptrTft->height(), ILI9341_BLACK);
        ptrTft->setCursor(0, 0);

        ptrTft->print(F("01234567890"));
        delay(250);
    }

    Adafruit_GFX *ptrTft;
};

test instance;

void setup() {
    tft = new Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC);

    tft->begin();
    tft->setTextSize(2);

    instance.init(tft);
}


void outsideClassRotation(Adafruit_GFX *passed) {
    passed->setRotation(newRotationAngle);
    drawStuff();
}


void loop(void) {
    newRotationAngle++;

    // This works. No problems.
//    outsideClassRotation(tft);

    // This does NOT rotate but still prints the text fine.
    instance.inClassRotation(newRotationAngle);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually be quite surprised if `outsideClassRotation()` actually
worked. My guess is that *it does not work as is*. Maybe it did work at
some point, but then you made some subtle changes to your code and did
not check that it is still working.

Here is the deal: there are two `setRotation()` methods:

- `Adafruit_GFX::setRotation(unsigned char)` does very little besides
  storing the rotation angle... which is not used anyway.
- `Adafruit_ILI9341::setRotation(unsigned char)` actually sends commands
  to the LCD asking it to apply the rotation; this is the method you
  want.

The problem is that *these methods are not `virtual`*, which means that
when you call them through a pointer, as in
`some_pointer->setRotation(the_angle);`, you get the method
corresponding to *the type of the pointer*, not the type of the actual
object. For example:

```c++
tft->setRotation(the_angle);     // calls Adafruit_ILI9341::setRotation()
ptrTft->setRotation(the_angle);  // calls Adafruit_GFX::setRotation()
passed->setRotation(the_angle);  // calls Adafruit_GFX::setRotation()
```

I checked this by uncommenting your call to `outsideClassRotation()` and
disassembling the compiled binary: both times you are calling
`Adafruit_GFX::setRotation()`.

**Solution**: change your `Adafruit_GFX *` pointers to be of
type `Adafruit_ILI9341 *`, or patch Adafruit_GFX.h to make
`setRotation()` virtual.

Comment: Actually, outsideClassRotation() works regardless, but you solved my mystery. I knew it was something simple.  I can only unlock bounty after 18 hours. Thanks!!!